# Where to get custom Visual Studio 2008 syntax highlighting (complex one)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

Ok, im used to see some more syntax highlighting, and the default syntax highlighting is really limited in VS 2008, so i was thinking, is there such highlighting somewhere:

1. defined variables would have own color.
2. defined functions would have own color.
3. predefined functions would have own color (from libs etc, would have own list for these perhaps).
4. constants/enums would have own color.
5. typedefs/defs would have own color.
6. strings (stuff between quotes) would have own color.
7. floats/doubles would be colored differently (would check for 1.0f or 1.0 etc)

Because this would be totally awesome, i havent seen 1,2,4,5 in any syntax highlighting systems before, it would be nice to have such. This would speed up programming a lot since if i make a mistake i would see it instantly before compiling.

I watched some MSDN site and it was pretty complicated to do it, so im hoping if theres already existing stuff so i could just download it and so on.

Comment: Looks like a job for a custom VS plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Visual Assist X plug-in from Whole Tomato software:

http://www.wholetomato.com/

I think it takes care of most of the items on your list.

Comment: awesome, it even had auto completion for variables :D ive been wanting that too ^_^ too bad the coloring options were quite limited... well, its better anyways so ill just use this.

Comment: There are more coloring options than you might think.  Go to "Tools->Options...", then under "Environment" go to the "Fonts and Colors" item.  Under the list of Display items, there are a lot of items for which the color can be adjusted, including a few added by Visual Assist X.